# What types of hacking attacks happen alongside a DOS or DDOS attack?

Tags: web-application, mysql, denial-of-service, ddos

I'm trying to find some good material on this topic for a paper I'm trying to write for class. Any and all help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Spoofing. When the actual services go down, attacker tries to spoof as if he's the service provider and starts collecting secret information. For example, within an enterprise network, one could DoS a DNS server and start dummy instance of DNS (with same ip, but probably different MAC -- even same MAC sometimes by spoofing) and wrongly resolving the domain names to malicious IP and then further installing a honeynet to collect various secret info. At Internet scale DDoS generally is done only to bring down certain services, but if a targeted attack is being carried out then probably the assumption at application level of availablity of certain service might not hold and hence may lead to certain specific security hole (its very situation specific, one needs to study the application architecture to understand implication of certain services going down).

Found that this is a duplicate of [Does a DDoS attack have other purposes beyond a lack of availability?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42621/does-a-ddos-attack-have-other-purposes-beyond-a-lack-of-availability) (which is in itself a duplicate of another question, pls follow link)